# Disable smoothing of UVMap coordinates between 1.0 and 0.0 (at seams)

Tags: uv, geometry-nodes

is there a way to disable smoothing of UVMap coordinates (not texture, but coordinates) at seams ?

I believe blender smooths transition between 1.0 and 0.0 (or values close to it),
what I currently get is ... 0.8 ... 0.9 ... 0.5 ... 0.1 (notice blender trying to smooth the jump by inserting 0.5 after 0.9).

This is also visible if I display UV coorinates as colors on UV sphere vertices:[image: UV sphere with UV cooridnates as colors]

Notice blender trying to smooth transition from green to yellow by inserting 1 value in-between them. Again, what I want is a sudden fall from 1.0 (or 0.9 if 1.0 nowhere to place) to 0.0 (so that it's sudden jump from green to yellow on image). Is that possible to do with default blender's UV unwrapping ? If not then what about manual UV unwrapping ?

update:

Here's the node setup I'm using to store a UV coordinate per each vertex (there's additionaly a "Viewer" node that displays UVs on vertices just to illustrate the issue):
[image: node setup]
("Some work with UVs" frame is just a placeholder for node setup where I need UVs to be in before-mentioned format)

Comment: This happens, because UV Map attribute is stored on Face Corners. 
Why exactly do you need to sharpen it and is using geometry nodes possible in your project?

Comment: I'm trying to apply multivariable function z=f(x,y) on UV coordinates and then move respective point on the object along the normal * z. The function wraps x and y in sin/cos so transition from 1 to 0 should be smooth (1 and 0 are mapped to 2*pi and 0 respectively).

Yes, I'm doing this in geometry nodes and UV coordinates I get by using "Capture Attribute" (per point) + "Named Attribute" (UVMap)

Comment: The solution to your problem will be to store the attribute on faces, I suppose. Without more context(node setup) I may be wrong with my assumption

Comment: I have only vertices, no faces between them, meaning I can't store attribute per face. Or do you mean something else ? (I've attached a screenshot of node setup)

Comment: Oh, I see, It's a bit different from what I thought about initially. For what reason do you need the mesh to points?

Answer (score 0):

I've got it working, here's the result I needed:
[image: result]

And here's the node setup:
[image: node setup]

Not sure how exactly "Sample nearest surface" works, but it gives the result I need.